# can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `ClassName' value

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Что интересно, если под строкой с ошибкой добавить подобную строку, то ошибка сместится ниже на новую строку. Ошибка двигается на одну строку вверх относительно самого нижнего объявления объекта.

В некоторых случаях может выводить ошибку типа:

```
found `std::ios_base::Init::Init()' instead
```

Чистку проекта делал, не помогло.

```
using namespace std;
int system(const char * string);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  createConnection();

  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  SwitchProviderSMTP *prov = new SwitchProviderSMTP(); // Ошибка
  ProviderSMTP *prv = new ProviderSMTP();

  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: для какого то с объектов - SwitchProviderSMTP или ProviderSMTP не все функции определены.

Comment: @shaman888 что такое ClassName? где его реализация?

Comment: ClassName это любой класс который будет находиться на строке ошибки. В данном случае в том месте SwitchProviderSMTP. Просматриваю определения функций классов, но пока не обнаружил не одного пропуска.

Comment: попробовал создать функцию в классе без объявления, но компилятор сразу выдал ошибку, из чего делаю вывод о том, что все функции у меня определены.

Comment: перейдите в h файл, где объявлены классы и кликнув правой кнопкой по имени класса после слова class, в подменю Refactor найдите "Insert virtual function". Оно предложит список функций и отметит галочками нужные.

Comment: @kovadim про подобную функцию знаю, но для неопределённых функций у меня там: Add Definition in classname.cpp. Сейчас ни для какой функции подобное не высвечивает. Осталась только функция переименования.

Comment: Даже если взять во внимание необъявленную функцию, то почему же тогда при объявлении объектов класса по одному, ошибки нет?

Comment: Такое бывает ещё в одном случае - если не перегенерировался make file. А его иногда нужно добровольно-принудительно. Особенно это хорошо воспроизводиться, если сделать какой-то существующий класс наследником QObject.

Comment: удалил всё пересобрал, результат тот же

Answer (score 1):

Вместо решения, может быть кого нибудь натолкнёт на правильное решение:
Создал новый проект, перенёс все файлы, ошибки нет. Вывод проблема в автоматически создаваемых файлах Qt но как её исправить так и не сообразил. Не переносить же каждый раз код заново. К тому же возможно причина была в том, что названия файлов и папок содержали символ "_" при переносе проекта файлы переименовал. Конечно пробовал переименовать названия и в основном проекте. Возможно проблема лежит в области сигналов-слотов. Поскольку я их то создавал, то удалял, и возможно объявлял не корректно.

Если вопрос кому-то кажется на столько тривиальным, что был поставлен минус, то у меня есть надежда что он в конечном счёте разрешится.